# CustomAdapter ListView is not updating

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, bluetooth, android-viewpager

I got this list which grabs all found Bluetooth devices when they are discovered. And an adapter which should go and add them to a `ListView` which is inside a `Fragment` which is inside a `ViewPager`. The list itself and the adapter do update, but the `ListView` doesn't get updated.
To test the code I used I made a new project, in which it works perfectly.
So my question is, can anyone point out why my ListView inside a `ViewPager` doesn't update, but the one outside of it does work?

Here's my code:
Assigning variables

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_settings);
mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.device_list);
...
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter = new BluetoothArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.device_layout, mDevices);
mList.setEmptyView(mEmpty);
mList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Method that is called to fill the Adapter

```
@Override
public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        ....
        mDevices.add(device);
        mList.invalidate();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ....
    }
}
```

BluetoothArrayAdapter:

```
public class BluetoothArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> {

    public BluetoothArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> values) {
        super(context, resource, values);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        Log.i("Adapter", "Inside getview");
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.device_layout, null);
        }

        BluetoothDevice p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView deviceName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            TextView deviceAddress = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.device_address);

            if(deviceName != null) {
                deviceName.setText(p.getName());
            }
            if(deviceAddress != null)
                deviceAddress.setText(p.getAddress());

        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

ViewPager:

```
public class SectionsViewPager extends ViewPager {    
    public SectionsViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public SectionsViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
        if(v != this && v instanceof ViewPager) { return true; }
        return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a MainFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return MainFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show amount of pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "SECTION " + position;
    }
}
```

And my layouts:
device_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/device_empty"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dip"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="Bluetooth device"
    android:src="@drawable/remote_icon_transparent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/device_address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="MAC address"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/device_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/device_address"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<View style="@style/Divider"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_setting:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/device_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:text="No Devices"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you confirm the logs that is it actually adding the data?

Comment: The logs says that both the list and the adapter gain items, but the ListView doesn't get any Children.

Comment: Could you post the code of your ViewPager and its adapter plz ?

Comment: I added the code for ViewPager and the adapter

Comment: OK I post the answer. Use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.
The reason why my `ListView` wasn't updating was because I set the adapter of it in my main `Activity`, when I should've called it in my `Fragment`.
When I put the code there my `ListView` updated like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line too your code after your setting adapter:
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I already called that. I called it in the method that is called to fill the Adapter

Answer (score 0):

regarding your question about the list view not updating i once encountered the same problem but with different adapters... the solution to me was to call the method which updates or executes the list view update on the onResume() method which you can ovveride since the oncreate gets executed once and thus your list view will work only one time so try using your code in the onResume() method of your activity. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried adding the code which sets the adapter in onResume, but the same thing still happens. Should I put any other code in there?

Comment: yes try calling onResume() in your activity after doing the changes

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. To make the fragment inside ViewPager to redraw, use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Hope it help :)

Comment: Did you call `notifyDataSetChange` on this adapter ? You have to call on adapter of `ListView` and adapter of `ViewPager`